# Spliting a big file in to multiple?

Tags: linux, command, split

I have a big file run_simulation.csh of about 1000 line

```
#!/bin/csh                                                                                                                                                               
set config_dir = /proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/input
set testbench_dir = /proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/testbench/TT_p025c
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_0_0.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_0_1.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_0_2.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_0_3.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_1_0.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_1_1.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_1_2.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
bsub $testbench_dir/cell/delay_1_3.sp.py -c $config_dir/sim.config.py -m 1
...............
```

I would like to split this file into small file of 50 lines and they must have the first 3 line of big file run_simulation.csh. If possible, these small file have extension .csh. How do I do this spliting ? by command ?

```
#!/bin/csh                                                                                                                                                               
set config_dir = /proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/input
set testbench_dir = /proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/testbench/TT_p025c
```

Comment: Are you in fact running `bsub` on all file with a particular filename pattern in a directory? You could do that with a three line loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# step 1: Remove the header:
tail -n +4 ./bigfile.csh > bigfile_without_header.csh

# step 2: Split the file:
split -d -l 1000 --additional-suffix=.csh ./bigfile_without_header.csh split-

# step 3: Add the header back to each file:
HEADER='#!/bin/csh\nset config_dir = /proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/input\nset testbench_dir = /proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/testbench/TT_p025c\n'
sed -i "1s,^,$HEADER," split-*.csh
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example, tested with `bash`:

```
#! /bin/bash 
# first sub file index
j=1
# first line after header
i=4
# 50 lines per sub file
lines=50
# lines in file to split
total_lines=$(cat file_to_cut | wc -l)

while [ $i -lt $total_lines ]
do 
    # copy header
    head -n 3 example > sub_file_$j
    # copy data
    tail -n +$i fite_to_cut | head -n $lines >> sub_file_$j
    # prepare next file
    j=$((j+1))        
    # prepare next line to read
    i=$((i+$lines))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to `bsub` every script that matches the pattern `"$testbench_dir"/cell/delay_*_*.sp.py`, then you may replace your script with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

config_dir=/proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/input
testbench_dir=/proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/testbench/TT_p025c

for py in "$testbench_dir"/cell/delay_*_*.sp.py; do
    bsub "$py" -c "$config_dir/sim.config.py" -m 1
done
```

This is a `/bin/sh` script, not a `csh` script, but that should not matter.

If you need ensure that the scripts are executed in a particular order (the above would sort the script files in lexicographical order), then do a double loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

config_dir=/proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/input
testbench_dir=/proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/testbench/TT_p025c

maxi=300   # the largest number I in delay_I_J.sp.py
maxj=3     # the largest number J in delay_I_J.sp.py

i=0
until [ "$i" -gt "$maxi" ]; do
    j=0
    until [ "$j" -gt "$maxj" ]; do
        bsub "$testbench_dir/cell/delay_${i}_${j}.sp.py" -c "$config_dir/sim.config.py" -m 1
        j=$(( j + 1 ))
    done
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

---

If you want the script to only submit jobs in batches of 50, and to be able to tell it on the command line what batch to submit with e.g.

```
./script 3
```

(would run batch 3, i.e. jobs 100-149)

```
#!/bin/sh

batch=$1

if [ -z "$batch" ]; then
    printf 'Usage: %s batchnumber\n' "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

bstart=$(( (batch - 1)*50 ))
bend=$(( batch*50 - 1 ))

printf 'Submitting batch %d (jobs %d to %d)\n' "$batch" "$bstart" "$bend"

config_dir=/proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/input
testbench_dir=/proj/ABC/users/nhannguyen/work/verif/qc/testbench/TT_p025c

count=0
for py in "$testbench_dir"/cell/delay_*_*.sp.py; do
    if [ "$count" -gt "$bend" ]; then
        break
    fi

    if [ "$count" -ge "$bstart" ]; then        
        bsub "$py" -c "$config_dir/sim.config.py" -m 1
    fi

    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
```